# how do i check all elements of an array are the same?

Tags: php, arrays

ie, verify

```
$a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1;
```

but not

```
$a[0]=1; $a[0]=2; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1; $a[0]=1;
```

thanks :)

Comment: I think your indexes are slightly wrong...

Comment: yup, you're just declaring one element and then resetting its value  over and over

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
count(array_unique($a)) == 1;
```

Comment: Wow. I'm not a great fan of PHP (it works well, but is not very beautiful), but it does have some handy functions. Just the one significance needed, in this case.

Comment: To nipick, it should be `count(array_unique($a)) <= 1`; if the array has no elements, then the proposition "all the elements are the same" is true.

Comment: MvanGeest - i find that happens often in php! Wrikken - thanks - elegant solution!

Comment: more formally, the proposition "exists some value `A` such as for any value `B` in the array `ARR`, `A=B`" is true if `ARR` is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Check if all items are equal to the first item:

```
$first = $array[0];
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($a != $first) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to PHP, then it might be easier for you to use it in this way

```
function chkArrayUniqueElem($arr) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
            if($arr[$i] != $arr[$j]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Other variants brought up earlier are more simple in use.

Comment: How on earth is that easier for a beginner?

Comment: Well IMHO it is. At least when I started learning it was. You can see every move in this function. Nothing passes you.