# in php, how to check if an array item differs from the rest

Tags: php, arrays

in PHP, how do I check if at least 1 item in an array differs from the rest? eg.

```
$array(3, 3, 3, 3); // returns false

$array(3, 3, 5, 3, 2); // returns true

$array(3, 3, 5, 3, 3); // returns true
```

The array has an indefinite number of items. Is there an algorithm for this?

Thanks

Comment: This should be useful i think: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075643/how-do-i-check-all-elements-of-an-array-are-the-same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
  $a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'a');
  if (count(array_unique($a)) > 1) {
  }
```

Comment: You could leave out the call to `array_values`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the more manual way:

```
<?php
$array = array(3, 3, 3, 3);
$different = false;
for($i=1;i<count($array);i++)
{
    if($array[$i] != $array[$i-1])
    {
        $different = true;
    }
}
?>
```